# Scala function transformation

Tags: scala, functional-programming, closures

Say I've got a function taking one argument

```
def fun(x: Int) = x
```

Based on that, I want to generate a new function with the same calling convention, but that'll apply some transformation to its arguments before delegating to the original function. For that, I could

```
def wrap_fun(f: (Int) => Int) = (x: Int) => f(x * 2)
wrap_fun(fun)(2) // 4
```

How might one go about doing the same thing, except to functions of any arity that only have the part of the arguments to apply the transformation to in common?

```
def fun1(x: Int, y: Int) = x
def fun2(x: Int, foo: Map[Int,Str], bar: Seq[Seq[Int]]) = x

wrap_fun(fun1)(2, 4) // 4
wrap_fun(fun2)(2, Map(), Seq()) // 4
```

How would a `wrap_fun` definition making the above invocations work look like?

Comment: Fwiw, such things can be really simple in dynamic languages: http://ideone.com/MYP2W.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done in fairly straightforwardly using [shapeless's](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) facilities for abstracting over function arity,

```
import shapeless._
import HList._
import Functions._

def wrap_fun[F, T <: HList, R](f : F)
  (implicit
    hl :   FnHListerAux[F, (Int :: T) => R],
    unhl : FnUnHListerAux[(Int :: T) => R, F]) =
      ((x : Int :: T) => f.hlisted(x.head*2 :: x.tail)).unhlisted

val f1 = wrap_fun(fun _)
val f2 = wrap_fun(fun1 _)
val f3 = wrap_fun(fun2 _)
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> f1(2)
res0: Int = 4

scala> f2(2, 4)
res1: Int = 4

scala> f3(2, Map(), Seq())
res2: Int = 4
```

Note that you can't apply the wrapped function immediately (as in the question) rather than via an assigned val (as I've done above) because the explicit argument list of the wrapped function will be confused with the implicit argument list of `wrap_fun`. The closest we can get to the form in the question is to explicitly name the `apply` method as below,

```
scala> wrap_fun(fun _).apply(2)
res3: Int = 4

scala> wrap_fun(fun1 _).apply(2, 4)
res4: Int = 4

scala> wrap_fun(fun2 _).apply(2, Map(), Seq())
res5: Int = 4
```

Here the explicit mention of `apply` syntactically marks off the first application (of `wrap_fun` along with its implicit argument list) from the second application (of the transformed function with its explicit argument list).

Comment: This is very cool!  Is there a possibility of getting more explicit documentation of this (specifically, `FnHListerAux` and `FnUnHListerAux`) on the GitHub page (be it in the readme or on the wiki)?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's on my TODO list, but if you have the time and inclination a pull request for documentation would be very welcome :-)

Answer (score 6):

As usual in Scala, there's yet another way to achieve what you want to do.

Here is a take based on currying of the first argument together with the `compose` of `Function1`:

```
def fun1(x : Int)(y : Int) = x
def fun2(x : Int)(foo : Map[Int, String], bar : Seq[Seq[Int]]) = x

def modify(x : Int) = 2*x
```

The resulting types as REPL shows you will be:

```
fun1: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int
fun2: (x: Int)(foo: Map[Int,String], bar: Seq[Seq[Int]])Int
modify: (x: Int)Int
```

And instead of wrapping the functions `fun1` and `fun2`, you `compose` them, as technically, they are now both `Function1` objects. This allows you to make calls like the following:

```
(fun1 _ compose modify)(2)(5)
(fun2 _ compose modify)(2)(Map(), Seq())
```

Both of which will return 4. Granted, the syntax is not that nice, given that you have to add the `_` to distinguish `fun1`'s application from the function object itself (on which you want to call the `compose` method in this case).

So Luigi's argument that it is impossible in general remains valid, but if you are free to curry your functions you can do it in this nice way.

Answer (score 2):

Since functions taking different numbers of arguments are different, unrelated types, you cannot do this generically. `trait Function1 [-T1, +R] extends AnyRef` and nothing else. You will need a separate method for each arity.

Comment: I wouldn't say 'cannot'. [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) has some cool features for abstracting over arity. Since [liftO](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/src/main/scala/shapeless/lift.scala) can work with functions of arbitrary arity, this should be possible.

Comment: @dave Shapeless makes it possible by writing all possible cases -- both tuples and functions only go up to arity 22, since Scala can't abstract over them either, so each one has to be defined.

Comment: @daniel No, there's no need to enumerate all cases to do this with shapeless ... see my answer.

Comment: @MilesSabin Well, but _you_ enumerated them on Shapeless so that Shapeless users wouldn't have to, right? This is what I meant. Am I wrong?

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral That's right. Your comment seemed to be suggesting that an enumeration of cases would be needed to solve this specific problem. That's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

While I voted for and agree with Luigi's answer–because, you know... he's *right*; Scala *doesn't* have direct, in-built support for such a thing–it's worth noting that what you're trying to do isn't *impossible*; it's just that it's a bit of a pain to pull off, and, often times, you're best off just implementing a separate method per desired arity.

That said, though... we can actually do this `HList`s.  If you're interested in trying it out, naturally, you'll need to obtain an `HList` implementation.  I recommend utilizing Miles Sabin's excellent [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) project and its implementation of `HList`s.  Anyway, here's an example of its use that accomplishes something akin to what you seem to be looking for:

```
import shapeless._

trait WrapperFunner[T] {
  type Inputs <: HList
  def wrapFun(inputs: Inputs) :  T
}

class WrapsOne extends WrapperFunner[Int] {
  type Inputs = Int :: HNil
  def wrapFun(inputs: Inputs) : Int = {
    inputs match {
      case num :: HNil => num * 2
    }
  }
}

class WrapsThree extends WrapperFunner[String] {
  type Inputs = Int :: Int :: String :: HNil
  def wrapFun(inputs: Inputs) : String = {
    inputs match {
      case firstNum :: secondNum :: str :: HNil => str + (firstNum - secondNum)
    }
  }
}

object MyApp extends App {

  val wo = new WrapsOne
  println(wo.wrapFun(1 :: HNil))
  println(wo.wrapFun(17 :: HNil))
  //println(wo.wrapFun(18 :: 13 :: HNil))  // Would give type error

  val wt = new WrapsThree
  println(wt.wrapFun(5 :: 1 :: "your result is: " :: HNil))
  val (first, second) = (60, 50)
  println(wt.wrapFun(first :: second :: "%s minus %s is: ".format(first, second) :: HNil))
  //println(wt.wrapFun(1 :: HNil))  // Would give type error

}
```

Running `MyApp` results in:

```
2
34
your result is: 4
60 minus 50 is: 10
```

Or, extended closer to your particular case:

```
import shapeless._

trait WrapperFunner[T] {
  type Inputs <: HList
  def wrapFun(inputs: Inputs) :  T
}

trait WrapperFunnerBase extends WrapperFunner[Int] {
  // Does not override `Inputs`
  def wrapFun(inputs: Inputs) : Int = {
    inputs match {
      case (num: Int) :: remainder => num
    }
  }
}

class IgnoresNothing extends WrapperFunnerBase {
  type Inputs = Int :: HNil
}

class IgnoresLastTwo extends WrapperFunnerBase {
  type Inputs = Int :: Int :: String :: HNil
}

object MyApp extends App {

  val in = new IgnoresNothing
  println(in.wrapFun(1 :: HNil))
  println(in.wrapFun(2 :: HNil))
  //println(in.wrapFun(3 :: 4 :: HNil))  // Would give type error

  val ilt = new IgnoresLastTwo
  println(ilt.wrapFun(60 :: 13 :: "stupid string" :: HNil))
  println(ilt.wrapFun(43 :: 7  :: "man, that string was stupid..." :: HNil))
  //println(ilt.wrapFun(1 :: HNil))  // Would give type error

}
```

results in:

```
1
2
60
43
```

Comment: You've really made a bit of a mean of this I'm afraid! See my answer for a much simpler solution using shapeless.

Comment: @MilesSabin Yes, I expected that my way wouldn't the best one possible.  Thanks for offering a far superior solution!